# I am trying to replace all non-word character and non-numbers with an empty string in the string array

Tags: java, regex

```
line = br.readLine();
list = line.split(" ");

for(int i =0;i<list.length;i++)
{

      list[i].replaceAll("[A-Za-z0-9]","");

}
```

Input

Subject: re : issue *()&&&*

output that I am getting

Subject:  // ":" should have been removed

re

:         //  should have been removed

issue

// Expected output

Subject

re

issue

Comment: And what is the question here?

Comment: I really cannot figure out what is going on here. Your question is not clear about what is your input, what you want to get and what youa are actually getting.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll)

```
line1 = line1.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]","");
```